# Linux rename regex

Tags: regex, linux

I want to rename name of files test123..-1.in, test123..-2.in, etc. to test123.in.

I tried commands:

> rename -/d.in .in *.in, and many of similar but no one works(Can You explain why?).
>   Then i tried rename 's/.[0-9]*.in$/.in/' *.in, with same result..

Any proposition how to solve this problem in the simple way? I dont wanna write it mannualy.

Thanks for Your help.

Comment: Why do you want to rename every file to test123.in? There will be only one file at the end of execution.

Comment: Do you actually want to rename files to have the same file name (which makes no sense), or do you want to merge several files into one file?

Comment: No, I have many test files, that why i wrote test123... with points. They accualy will be like test12345-5, test12346-3, test12353-2 etc. and i want them be only like test12345, test12346, test12353.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `rename`:

```
rename 's/\.+-\d+\././' test123..-*in
```

or as per OP's comment below:

```
rename 's/-\d+\.in/.in/' *.in
```

Comment: Accualy it is not what i want but it show me how i should do that, so thanks You :)
`rename 's/-\d+.in/.in/' *.in`